# Is there a way to reset a profile picture to a previous one?

Tags: support, profile-picture

If I change a profile picture, is there a way I can later change it to a past image, or will I need to find the source of the first image and re-upload it manually?

Comment: If its gravatar - it should have the old ones saved. I doubt it is in your case though ...

Comment: When I changed my avatar between the hedgehog and werehog forms, I'd have to save the prior image so I could switch back.

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed a dupe (by someone else with "forest" in their name, no less!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you chose Gravatar to host your profile picture (though there's a lot of great reasons not to use it) - it keeps track of all the pictures you have used there over time.

Imgur avatars are not logged in any end-user accessible way from what I can see. They are still 'there' on imgur, but if you have those images, re-uploading is likely the easier way.

Comment: The URLs are present in SEDE and the data dump, though (Users -> ProfileImageURL), so if SEDE hasn't updated yet you can track the URL down easily that way, else if you had it for years, it's probably in a dump. Though re-uploading may still be easier.

Comment: Well - finding it is one problem - and almost certainly an answer on its own right.